# como evitar que una funcion javascript en un a href redireccione a la referecia

Tags: javascript, php, html

Saludos tengo el siguiente codigo que genera links de manera dinámica desde php, en base a una consulta a una BD.

```
...
$html='<a  id="prbCat" onclick="queDeseaElUsuario();false;" href="'.$linkenv.'">';
return $html;
...
```

Adicionalmente la función **queDeseaElUsuario()** es una funcion Javascript que solicitar una acción del usuario necesaria antes de la redirección.

debido a que el html se genera desde php, no visualizo la manera de detener el redireccionamiento (esto debido a mi desconocimiento) he visto aca en el foro esta solucion presentada por yikarus

```
document.getElementById('prbCat').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let respuesta = queDeseaElUsuario(); 
  ...
});
```

que previene que se redireccione, haciendo el siguiente cambio en el a href

```
$html='<a  id="prbCat" href="'.$linkenv.'">';
return $html;
```

pero esto entonces no ejecuta la función y el redireccionamiento si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo cambiando esto:

```
$html='<a id="prbCat" href="'.$linkenv.'">';
```

por esto:

```
$html='<a class="prbCat" href="'.$linkenv.'">';
```

para conseguir que tengas varios enlaces que puedan ser de ese tipo. Al usar solo un **id** éste será único con el getElementById, de tal modo que tan solo encontrará el primero de ellos y no te permitirá ejecutar el resto, si es que hay más.

Luego los buscamos con [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) de este modo:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.prbCat').forEach((x) => {
```

y así vamos a encontrarlos todos, y sobre cada uno de ellos les aplicamos lo siguiente:

```
  x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let respuesta = queDeseaElUsuario();
    location.assign(x.href)
  });
```

que gracias al [`location.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location#ejemplo_1_navegar_a_una_nueva_p%C3%A1gina) vamos a realizar su redireccionamiento desde javascript, pero dirigiéndonos en cada caso al valor del href del elemento clicado, gracias a su atributo href, el cual localizamos de este modo: `x.ref`

### Ejemplo completo

```js
function queDeseaElUsuario() {
  console.log("lo que sea que haga esta función antes del redireccionamiento")
}

document.querySelectorAll('.prbCat').forEach((x) => {
  x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let respuesta = queDeseaElUsuario();
    location.assign(x.href)
  });

});
```

```html
<a class="prbCat" href="https://www.google.es">Google</a>
<a class="prbCat" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

Comment: saludos, no sé, que pueda estar pasando pero no ejecuta la función de **querySelectorAll** entonces al implementarlo no hace nada, laprobe en codepen.io y funciona bien, pero al llevarlo a la pagina donde estoy no se ejecuta

Comment: ya has cambiado el `id="prbCat"` por `class="prbCat"` en los enlaces?

Comment: correcto, si elimine id y coloque class

Comment: lo que me parece raro es que si yo coloco la función como un `onclick="queDeseaElUsuario();"` pues funciona la llamada a la mencionada función, con el detalle que he dicho previamente

Comment: ¿y aun no te funciona? pues no se que decirte, no es una función extraña, es de javascript puro y debería funcionar... ¿y si le pones console.log() por dentro no ves que entre?

Comment: exacto por eso digo que no la ejecuta tengo un console.log en 'queDeseaElUsuario();' y luego de e.preventDefault(); y ninguno se ejecuta, claro en la página hay una mezcla de js, php y html que para que contar (ya estaba así)

Comment: no, pero a ver... lo que haga `queDeseaElUsuario();` me trae un poco sin cuidado, pues no está en la pregunta ni se lo que hace... yo digo que pongas un console.log **antes** de llamar a esa función para ver si al menos entra en el bucle

Comment: si como dije lo coloque luego de `e.preventDefault();`. y no se ejecuta

Comment: pues ni idea... supongo que esos enlaces `<a>` no son creados dinámicamente (eso podría ser el problema) y que esa parte del código javascript se lee bien como tal (si acaso ponle un console.log una línea **antes** del `document.querySelectorAll` para ver si llega a interpretarse al menos eso... y si eso no se interpreta es porque está mal puesto en la página por lo que sea (pulsa F12 para ver la consola y mira si hay errores por alguna parte tambien)

Comment: chevere gracias en verdad, pruebo y busco a ver si hay alguna otra cosa que este afectando, que asumo debe ser asi y comento, (indicame si valido vuestra respuesta ya que en efecto eso es lo que deberia solventar) auque en mi caso especifico no lo haga

Comment: Sigue buscando tu problema, y cuando lo hayas solventado vuelve para aceptar esta respuesta o agregar la tuya (eso siempre que el escenario sea similar... si hablamos de otro entonces sí que deberías validar esta respuesta)

Comment: Saludos no me funcionó con javascript cosa que sigo sin entender, asi que agregue jquery (no creo sea la mejor opción) pero funcionó. Asumo que hay conceptos que no manejo bien o algo así. gracias Masterguru